# How to know the semantic similarity of words in a text using word2vec or WordNet in R?

Tags: r, word2vec, wordnet

I have a text and I want to know the semantic similarity score of all the words in a text with each other by using word2vec or WordNet in R. Is there any way to perform the analysis in R for this? Many thanks!

Comment: Just to clarify, when you say "semantic similarity score of all the words in a text with each other", do you mean calculate the pairwise similarity between all the words? So, if the text has (say) 10,000 unique words, you want to know the (10,000 * 10,000 / 2 =) 50 million word-to-word similarity scores?

Comment: Hi @gojomo. Thanks for your question! Yes I want to know the score of pairwise similarity between the words. Words here will be content words, rather than function words,... so I think the number of words in the text for calculating the scores will not be too high hopefully, if the text is around 1000 words in total. Sorry for not making it clearer in my question and many thanks for pointing this out!